# Name and age identifier JS

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I Established 4 variables (First Name, Last Name, Gender and Age).Im trying to use these variables to write a program that gathers the information for these variables from the user and then tests whether a specific user is male or female and whether they are 18 or older.  If 18 or older, the user will see the text Hello Mr./Ms. (based on gender) Last Name. If they are under 18, the user will see the text Hello First Name.

Below Is my code, can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? I've spent about a day trying to figure out how to write this code for myself. I want to also know what to replace "also if" with, Like i said I'm pretty new and don't really know all the function callers.

```
<script>
  var firstName, lastName, Age, Gender;
  alert("Please enter all the required spaces");
  Age = Number(prompt("Give me your age"));
  firstName = prompt("Give me your first name");
  lastName = prompt("Give me your last name");
  Gender = prompt("Give me your gender")
  
  function Teenager() {
    if Age < 18
    return prompt ("Hello" + firstName)
  }
  function Gender(0) {
    if Gender = female
    also if Age > 17
    return prompt("hello mrs" + lastName);
  }
  function Gender2() {
    if Gender = male
    also if Age > 17
    return prompt("hello mr" + lastName);
  }
  
  </script>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to get familiar with [basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) before asking at SO.

Comment: `if (` Condition `) {` Do this if true `} else {` Do this if false `}` `(`parenthesis`)` and `{`curly brackets`}` are your friends, never forget them.

Answer (score 2):

There are the following things you need to correct

- condition checking should be wrapped in parenthesis `()`
  eg: `if(Age < 18)`
- You should read about [if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) in js
- `prompt` is used to take input from the user and `alert` to inform.
- You need to use `===` for checking equality. `=` is used for assignment. like  `if (Gender === "female")`

```js
var firstName, lastName, Age, Gender;
alert("Please enter all the required spaces");
Age = Number(prompt("Give me your age"));
firstName = prompt("Give me your first name");
lastName = prompt("Give me your last name");
Gender = prompt("Give me your gender");

function testTeenager() {
  if (Age < 18) return alert("Hello " + firstName);
}

function testGenderAndAge() {
  if (Age >= 18) {
    if (Gender === "female") alert("hello mrs " + lastName);
    else prompt("hello mr " + lastName);
  }
}

testTeenager();
testGenderAndAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with If statements.

```
function reply() {
   If (age< 18) then  return Alert("Hello" + firstName)
   else if (gender = female) then return Alert("hello mrs" + lastName)
   else return Alert("hello mr" + lastName)
}

reply()
```

Comment: The code in your answer is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work.

```
function getTitle() {
    if (Age < 18) {
        return prompt ("Hello" + firstName)
    }
    else {
        if(Gender == 'female') {
            return prompt("hello mrs" + lastName);
        }
        if(Gender == 'male') {
            return prompt("hello mr" + lastName);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you made a lot of mistakes in the code, the first is JavaScript is very strict about the style of variables (Age or age) these are different variables. Then you don't call functions anywhere, then in your functions you try to assign new values ​​to the Gender variable. The following you did not correctly write the if else construction (you have if alse). Check out what I did in 5 minutes, partially using your code.

```
alert("Please enter all the required spaces");
let Age = +prompt("Give me your age");
let firstName = prompt("Give me your first name");
let lastName = prompt("Give me your last name");
let Gender = prompt("Give me your gender")

if (Age < 18) {
  alert(`You haven't grown yet, goodbye ${firstName}`);
} else {
  manOrWomen(lastName, Gender)
};

function manOrWomen(lastName, Gender) {
  if (Gender == 'male') {
    return alert(`hello mr ${lastName}`);
  } else {
    return alert(`hello mrs ${lastName}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you write was pseudo code.
• You need to enclose `if` conditions within `()` and code blocks of `if` within `{}`
• you need to use `===` to check for equality
• you need to use `&&` to specify more than one conditions that needs to be true along with others
• Variable name can't be same as function name
• You can use `if-else` conditions to make things easier
• `alert` is used to inform user while `prompt` is used to take input from user.

```js
var firstName, lastName, Age, gender;
alert("Please enter all the required spaces");
Age = Number(prompt("Give me your age"));
firstName = prompt("Give me your first name");
lastName = prompt("Give me your last name");
gender = prompt("Give me your gender")

function Teenager() {
  if (Age < 18){
    return prompt("Hello" + firstName);
    }
}

function Gender() {
  if (gender === "female" &&
     Age > 17){
    return prompt("hello mrs " + lastName);
    }
  else if (gender === "male" &&
     Age > 17){
    return prompt("hello mr " + lastName);
    }
}

Teenager();
Gender();
```